# I'm trying to detect the location of my mouse click when I click a hyperlink inside my Rich Text Box in WinForms, how would I do this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

So I'm trying to detect the location of my mouse click when I click a hyperlink inside my Rich Text Box in WinForms, how would I do this? I was thinking like a global mouse click for anywhere at anytime in the form would be the solution, however using forms or even panels mouse click events it only occurs when I don't click a control, which isnt what I want.

Comment: could you please post the solution you have tried so far?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Why do you care about the coordinates, and why display a hyperlink in an RTF box instead of a WebView?

Comment: i tried using a linkclicked event for the rtb in combination with a rtb mouseclick, as well as a rtb mousedown. The mouseclick or mousedown to try get the location of the mouse click when I click the hyperlink inside my rich text box, however, those events dont register when clicking the hyperlink so there's no way for me to retrieve the location of the click. I want to pop out another box beside the hyperlink inside the rtb, hence why I need the location of the link, since the link list will never be fixed.

Comment: You can always get the Control.MouseLocation and convert it to the client coordinates.

Comment: What is that you're looking for? The position of the first char of your link? The relative position of the Mouse Pointer (considering the ClientRectangle)? The absolute position of the Point clicked (considering the scrolling position of the Control)? Other...

Comment: the exact point of the mouse click when the hyperlink inside the rtb is clicked.

Comment: so ill try control.MouseLocation but how do I convert it to client coordinates?

Comment: `[Control].PointToClient(MousePosition)` (`MousePosition` or `Cursor.Position`)

Comment: @dutoit077, Is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to achieve the global mouse position when you click the hyperlink in the richtextbox.

You can use winapi `GetCursorPos` to get the goobal mouse position.

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Point lpPoint);
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(
                @"Google：http://www.google.cn/  c#：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/ testsssssssssssHelo,worldssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss");
            richTextBox1.LinkClicked += RichTextBox1_LinkClicked;
        }

        private void RichTextBox1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            var pt = new Point();

            GetCursorPos(ref pt);
            textBox1.Text = pt.X.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = pt.Y.ToString();
        }
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Why are you PInvoking when [MousePosition already calls GetCursorPos](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,3373) on its own (so does `Cursor.Position`)? It's in a comment on the question. If you keep on reading, then the OP asks: *how do I convert it to client coordinates*?

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys so I figured out a solution that worked for me

```
 private void dropDownBoxSite2Term2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
          //I use and bool to check if any link inside the rtb was clicked, and also grab //the text:
            subRTBLinkClicked = true;
            subRTBLinkText = e.LinkText;
        }

        //This is the rtb im using:
        private void dropDownBoxSite2Term3_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
//This is how i grabbed the client position:
                RTBDropDownLMBLocation = panel2.PointToClient(dropDownBoxSite2Term3.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));

//Using the bool from above i make an action occur
                if (subRTBLinkClicked)
                {
                     //make action happen that i need and use RTBDropDownLMBLocation
                     //for desired needs, like instantiate another textbox at click //position if needed for example
                 }
}
```

Hope this helps someone out there!

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.